# WPF Grid with an observablecollection as ItemsSource how to reorder it when a value in the collection is modified

Tags: wpf, gridview

Im  new with WPF, and I,m stuck with a thing that I thought would be easy to solve.
I have a gridView (telerik one), and it's ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection, it all works fine, I can see in the grid when a data is modified, when something is deleted or added, the grid is refreshed.
My problem is that when the collection is changed, the changed row goes to the last row in the grid, and I need to reorder it, I have tried to add a SortDescriptor  to sort the grid when the collection is changed, but nothing happens.

```
//This update changes function is the one that changes the collection    
updateChanges(field, new_value);
//This is the sortDescriptor that is supposed to order the grid
UIGlobal.MainPage.gridAnalog.SortDescriptors.Add(new SortDescriptor()
{
     Member = "ColName",
     SortDirection = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
});
```

And this is my grid

```
<telerik:RadGridView>
   <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="ColName" Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <telerik:GirdViewDataColumn Header="Value" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
   </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 </telerik:RadGridView>
```

I am tying to order it from the ColName column, but can't get it.

Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look to the ICollectionView and SortDescriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution I found, may help somebody.
I added a ColumnSortDescriptor to the grid:

```
//Establish grid's ItemsSource
grid.ItemsSource = observableDicData;    
//Remove previous SortDescriptors
grid.SortDescriptors.Clear();
//Add a SortDescriptor
ColumnSortDescriptor csd = new ColumnSortDescriptor()
{
     //In column is the UniqueName of the grid's column I want to sort by
     Column = this.grid.Columns["NameAnalog"],
     SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending
};
this.gridAnalog.SortDescriptors.Add(csd);
```

And I disabled the property of UserCanSort.

Answer (score 0):

I have never work with telerik, but you can try this:

```
//Add  reference  xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

<UserControll.Resources> 
 <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding YourCollection}" x:Key="sorted">
     <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         <scm:SortDescription  PropertyName="ColName" Direction="Ascending"/>
         </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         </CollectionViewSource>

</UserControll.Resources>                               
<telerik:RadGridView  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sorted}}"> 
   <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="ColName" Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <telerik:GirdViewDataColumn Header="Value" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
   </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: Hello @igor, thanks for your replay, adding a sortDescriptor was the solution, but I needed a ColumnSortDescriptor to make it work and did it through code